# julia, linear algebra, is there a function finding all vectors orthogonal to the given one?

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

For a given vector I would like to find the orthogonal basis around it,
i.e. the given vector normalized and randomly chosen basis of orthogonal sub-space.
Is there a convenient function for this in Julia?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called `nullspace`.

```
julia> x = randn(5);

julia> x⊥ = nullspace(x');

julia> x'x⊥
1×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 7.69373e-16  -5.45785e-16  -4.27252e-17  1.26778e-16
```

Comment: Indeed! (Also, pretty obvious..) And with the normalized `x` the full basis will be: `hcat(x / sqrt(x'x), nullspace(x'))'`

Comment: `x'` used to create a row matrix and it now just creates a `Adjoint` of the vector. You can make it work on recent versions of Julia with `nullspace(Matrix(x'))`. An attempt to make `nullspace(x')` work can be found in https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/33385/

Answer (score 8):

You could define a function orth (if someonehasn't already done this)

`orth(M) = qr(M)[1]`

See here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/eG6a4tj7LGg and http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/linalg/

Or from IterativeSolvers.jl:

`orthogonalize{T}(v::Vector{T}, K::KrylovSubspace{T})`

See:
https://github.com/JuliaMath/IterativeSolvers.jl

Comment: I seriously doubt you're going back to medicine after the PhD, Alex :D
(where excel sheets are considered IT wizardry)

Comment: thanks for suggestions! but I'll accept the answer with `nullspace` -- it's pretty basic, but fits the problem perfectly and should not be forgotten

Answer (score 2):

The following will calculate an orthogonal basis for matrix M

```
function orth(M::Matrix)
  matrixRank = rank(M)
  Ufactor = svdfact(M)[:U]
  return Ufactor[:,1:matrixRank]
end
```

With julia documentation:

````
"""
orth(M)

Compute an orthogonal basis for matrix `A`.

Returns a matrix whose columns are the orthogonal vectors that constitute a basis for the range of A.
If the matrix is square/invertible, returns the `U` factor of `svdfact(A)`, otherwise the first *r* columns of U, where *r* is the rank of the matrix.
# Examples
```julia
julia> orth([1 8 12; 5 0 7])
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.895625  -0.44481
 -0.44481    0.895625
```
```
julia> orth([1 8 12; 5 0 7 ; 6 4 1])
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.856421   0.468442   0.217036
 -0.439069  -0.439714  -0.783498
 -0.27159   -0.766298   0.582259
```
"""
function orth(M::Matrix)
  matrixRank = rank(M)
  Ufactor = svdfact(M)[:U]
  return Ufactor[:,1:matrixRank]
end
````